.NET MAUI MediaElement - very long buffering time
I'm using the .NET MAUI MediaElement to allow users watch previously uploaded videos from the cloud.
My code is almost identical to the given example, but unfortunately, the time to load a video is unacceptable.
Although I use hot storage, which is also located in my georegion, and my Internet connection is over 200Mbps, a standard 1080p 30FPS video takes about 10 seconds to start playing. Smaller low-res videos take less, but a longer 4K 60FPS takes nearly a minute!
Is this a known MediaElement problem? Or are there any best practices on how to set things up better here?

E.g., type of storage, video format, chunking, buffering or streaming parameters, etc.



Have you tried to Play local media to see if it has very long buffering time. 2. You can report it on CommunityToolkit/Maui. 3. And see this case: Higher quality HLS stream from youtube for Media Element in dotnet Maui.

